# Alerting data specifics inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm running into a javascript beginner's problem. I have this data stored in an array, and I'm trying to alert the data to see if it checks out.

I want to alert myself the average of the distance of **all**, not *both* planets even though both is all in this case, but I eventually want to have an array that keeps a lot more than just two. Right now, it just alerts the distance of the last record in the array list, which is weird. I thought it'd be an average for all.

Also, how do I program the least and highest numbers of the "Distance" property in the array, and then alert the "Host name" with it. So, if I have a button and I click on "Closest", the Host name of the lowest number in `"Distance [pc]"` will be alerted. I only need an example of the code for "Distance", so I'll know how to do the same for all other variables.

Thank you if you're willing to help out!

Btw, the list is JSON data. Maybe important to mention this.

```
    // this array holds the json data, in this case stastics of exoplanets retrieved from nasa's website   
    var arr=        [ {
   "rowid": 684,
   "Host name": "K2-15",
   "Number of Planets in System": 1,
   "Planet Mass or M*sin(i)[Jupiter mass]": null,
   "Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]": 0.221,
   "Planet Density [g": {
      "cm**3]": null
   },
   "Distance [pc]": 437,
   "Effective Temperature [K]": 5131,
   "Date of Last Update": "7/16/2015"
},
 {
   "rowid": 687,
   "Host name": "K2-17",
   "Number of Planets in System": 1,
   "Planet Mass or M*sin(i)[Jupiter mass]": null,
   "Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]": 0.199,
   "Planet Density [g": {
      "cm**3]": null
   },
   "Distance [pc]": 134,
   "Effective Temperature [K]": 4320,
   "Date of Last Update": "7/16/2015"
}];

    //every record is put in a variable  
    var rowid; 
    var hostName;
    var numberOfPlanetsInSystem;
    var planetMass;
    var planetRadius;
    var distance;
    var effectiveTemperature;

    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

       rowid= arr[i]["rowid"];
       hostName= arr[i]["Host name"];
       numberOfPlanetsInSystem= arr[i]["Number of Planets in System"];
       planetMass= arr[i]["Planet Mass or M*sin(i)[Jupiter mass]"];
       planetRadius= arr[i]["Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]"];
       distance= arr[i]["Distance [pc]"];
       effectiveTemperature= arr[i]["Effective Temperature [K]"];
    };

    //alert to test it out
    alert(distance);
```

Comment: You can output entire objects with console.log(distance). You can see them in the console in the developer tools in your browser.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/cdb54l <-- that statement in your comment is actually false. You are overwriting the values. There are two possible approaches: either increase the distance variable or follow a cleaner way, by replicating a key:value object with planetName:distance, then prototype an averagedistance function. The first one is the easiet one for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let totalDistance = maxDistance = 0;
let minDistance = arr[0]["Distance [pc]"];
let closestHost = farthestHost = "";
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
    totalDistance += arr[i]["Distance [pc]"]
    if (arr[i]["Distance [pc]"] < minDistance) {
        minDistance = arr[i]["Distance [pc]"];
        closestHost = arr[i]["Host name"];
    }
    if (arr[i]["Distance [pc]"] > maxDistance) {
        maxDistance = arr[i]["Distance [pc]"];
        farthestHost = arr[i]["Host name"];
    }
}
let meanDistance = totalDistance/arr.length;
```

Comment: This answer too says "NaN" when I console.log "meanDistance". Is it how I implement it that's the issue, or? I would love to try your answer out, could you like put it in a fiddle and see if it's working for yourself?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ashish_ranjan/ugqzxeg8/1/ its "Distance [pc] not Distance[pc]", I have edited my answer, you might be doing the same mistake.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it out and this is what I'm in need of. The closestHost doesn't seem to work though, whereas the farthestHost works just fine. It doesn't provide a name.

Comment: I built on your code. I've made it so that I can alert myself not just the lowest distance, furthest distance and total distance, but the lowest, highest and total number of all the planets' properties. But for each planet, the minus alert just doesn't seem to work. Could you please look into it? It won't alert a name at all and just keeps saying 0 instead of the lowest number.

 I'll keep your answer as accepted anyway because it's been really helpful, but further help with that last little problem would be really welcome!

Comment: sorry for the late reply, you see, I have done a mistake while initializing the minDistance, you initialize it like this ->    let minDistance = arr[0]["Distance [pc]"]; , you will get it working. I am updating the answer, while the jsFiddle is still the old one.

Comment: No worry about the late reply, thank you again for helping out. It works, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

In your cycle you are always overwrite your variable distance, not adding them.

Use `distance += arr[i]["Distance [pc]"]`

`+=` measn `distance = distance + arr[i]["Distance [pc]"]`

**EDIT**

Here is a working [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yns18rhz/)

You need to init `var distance = 0;`

```
    var distance = 0; //Important!
    var arr = [{
            "rowid": 684,
            "Host name": "K2-15",
            "Number of Planets in System": 1,
            "Planet Mass or M*sin(i)[Jupiter mass]": null,
            "Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]": 0.221,
            "Planet Density [g": {
                "cm**3]": null
            },
            "Distance [pc]": 437,
            "Effective Temperature [K]": 5131,
            "Date of Last Update": "7/16/2015"
        },
        {
            "rowid": 687,
            "Host name": "K2-17",
            "Number of Planets in System": 1,
            "Planet Mass or M*sin(i)[Jupiter mass]": null,
            "Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]": 0.199,
            "Planet Density [g": {
                "cm**3]": null
            },
            "Distance [pc]": 134,
            "Effective Temperature [K]": 4320,
            "Date of Last Update": "7/16/2015"
        }];


    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        distance += arr[i]["Distance [pc]"];
    };
    alert('Total distance: ' + distance + "\n" + 'Number of planets: ' + arr.length + "\n" + 'Average: ' + distance / arr.length);
```

Comment: If I do that, it just alerts me NaN. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `console.log(arr[i]["Distance [pc]"])` before you adding it, and check console.

Comment: That doesn't change the outcome. Can you copy my code and check if your answer works for you please. Does it give you the average of the two numbers?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  Both of these answers are great.